# Trigger a TouchDown on Button A during TouchDown of Button B

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to swap touch events for two buttons. When a button's TouchDown event is triggered, I load a new button on top of the one currently being touched. The problem is that I need this new button to be selected for dragging. I will need to cancel the TouchDown for the first button and then force it on the new button in order for the user to begin dragging it immediately. How can I manually call my `widgetTouch:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event` and have the touch persist?

Answer (score 2):

I would try `[button sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown]`

Comment: This works to an extent - the touch event is called, however it doesn't trigger my Touch Drag Inside events when I attempt to move.

Comment: Hmm... Is the button underneath reacting to that event still?

Comment: Also, what happens if you tell the button to becomeFirstResponder?

Comment: no, but only because I'm calling [control touchesCancelled:nil withEvent:event]; on the bottom button. Nothing new if I tell it to become the first responder.